# I get error for Deep Link for some Android 13 Devices

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-deep-link, android-13, android-13-deeplink

I'm getting deep link errors on many Android 13 devices, mostly Samsung devices.

[image]

[image]

I am not getting any errors on those device.

- Android - 13 - Galaxy Note20
- Android - 13 - Google Pixel

I made the necessary adjustments for `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```xml
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

...

       <intent-filter
           android:autoVerify="true"
           tools:targetApi="m">
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

           <data
              android:host="halilozel.com.tr"
              android:scheme="halilozel" />
      </intent-filter>
```

Code base :

```kotlin
fun getBrowserPackageName(context: Context): String? {
    val browserPackageName: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    try {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        intent.data = Uri.parse("http://www.aornzmenswqdt.mrgsscqsbgs")
        val pm = context.packageManager
        val browserList: List<ResolveInfo> = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0)
        for (info in browserList) {
            browserPackageName.add(info.activityInfo.packageName)
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    return when {
        browserPackageName.isEmpty() -> null
        browserPackageName.contains(PACKAGE_NAME_CHROME) -> PACKAGE_NAME_CHROME
        browserPackageName.contains(PACKAGE_NAME_OPERA) -> PACKAGE_NAME_OPERA
        else -> browserPackageName[0]
    }
}
```

```kotlin
fun Context.getBrowserIntent(url: String): Intent {
    val browserPackageName = getBrowserPackageName(this)
    if (browserPackageName != null) {
        val intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(browserPackageName)
        if (intent != null) {
            return intent.apply { data = Uri.parse(url) }
        }
    }

    val browserIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://"))
    val resolveInfo = packageManager.resolveActivity(browserIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)
    if (resolveInfo != null) {
        val packageName: String = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName
        val intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)
        if (intent != null) {
            return intent.apply { data = Uri.parse(url) }
        }
    }
    return Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, Intent.CATEGORY_APP_BROWSER).apply { data = Uri.parse(url) }
}
```

What kind of update was there for Android 13?

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers dropped handling uris passed as data for  Android 13 when using

```
Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, Intent.CATEGORY_APP_BROWSER)
```

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/243678703

Comment: You should tell more details. @bartsy